# Linq to xml. Determine the end of the tag

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a piece of xml like the following:

```
<side>
 <category>
   <title>Head</head>
   <item> Mister a </item>
 </category>
 <category>
   <title>Head</head>
   <item> Mister x </item>
   <item> Mister y </item>
 </category>
</side>
```

I am recovering for each category title and item and once arrived at the end of the category, place a separator that allows to separate categories. For now I can recover well for each category title and item, but I can not place a separator between two categories

this is my code in C# :

```
foreach (XElement node in doc.Descendants("category").Elements())
        {

                if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("titre"))
                {
                    layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                    {
                        Type = "Titre",
                        Contenu = node.Value
                    });

                }
                else if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("item"))
                {
                    layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                    {
                        Type = "Item",
                        Contenu = node.Value
                    });

                }
                else if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("item") && node.NextNode == null)
                {
                    layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                    {
                        Type = "Item",
                        Contenu = node.Value
                    });

                    layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                    {
                        Type = "Separateur",
                        Contenu = ""
                    });


                }




        }
        return layout.Records;
```

Comment: I cant post the xml correctly, how can i do that here ? My tag does not appear. Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been like -

```
foreach (XElement node in doc.Descendants("category").Elements())
        {
            if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("titre"))
            {
                layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                {
                    Type = "Titre",
                    Contenu = node.Value
                });
            }
            //This check requires here because at every item you won't get NextNode null except last one.
            else if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("item") && node.NextNode == null)
            {
                layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                {
                    Type = "Item",
                    Contenu = node.Value
                });

                layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                {
                    Type = "Separateur",
                    Contenu = ""
                });
            }
            else if (node.Name.LocalName.Equals("item"))
            {
                layout.Records.Add(new XMLRecord()
                {
                    Type = "Item",
                    Contenu = node.Value
                });

            }
        }
        return layout.Records;
```

Comment: Glad that, it helped you out. you can also mark it as answer/upvote.